# Using realloc inside a function for increasing an array

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, pass-by-reference, realloc

I am trying to call realloc inside of a function. My first call to the function seems to work, but my second call to it fails.

```
void insert(struct laptop *arr, struct laptop new_laptop, int* plen){
    arr = realloc(arr, (sizeof(struct laptop)*(*plen+1)));
    arr[*plen] = new_laptop;
    (*plen)++;
}

int main(){
    struct laptop* arr = malloc(sizeof(struct laptop));
    int len = 0;
    int *plen = &len;
    insert(arr, make_laptop("Dell", "XPS", "New", 500), plen);
    display(arr[0]);
    insert(arr, make_laptop("Macbook", "Pro", "New", 500), plen);
    display(arr[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

The rest of my code for reference:

```
struct laptop{
    char *brand;
    char *model;
    char *condition;
    float price;
};

struct laptop make_laptop(char *brand, char *model, char *condition, float price){
    struct laptop new_laptop;
    new_laptop.price = price;
    new_laptop.brand = malloc(strlen(brand)+1);
    strcpy(new_laptop.brand, brand);
    new_laptop.model = malloc(strlen(brand)+1);
    strcpy(new_laptop.model, model);
    new_laptop.condition = malloc(strlen(condition)+1);
    strcpy(new_laptop.condition, condition);
    return new_laptop;
}

void display(struct laptop laptop){
    printf("%s %s %s %.2f", laptop.brand, laptop.model, laptop.condition, laptop.price);
}
```

What is actually going on here? What are my options for fixing this?

Comment: Your second call fails because you pass `1` as `plen`.

Comment: You are passing `arr` by value. `realloc` may or may not return a different value than the value passed to it so if it does, the `arr` in `main` is not updated.

Comment: @tkausl I have fixed that, and the code still does not run properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters this memory allocation in main

```
struct laptop* arr = malloc(sizeof(struct laptop));
```

is redundamt. You should just write

```
struct laptop *arr = NULL;
```

The function accepts the pointer `arr` by value

```
void insert(struct laptop *arr, struct laptop new_laptop, int* plen){
    arr = realloc(arr, (sizeof(struct laptop)*(*plen+1)));
    arr[*plen] = new_laptop;
    (*plen)++;
}
```

that is the function deals with a copy of the value of the original pointer used as an argument.

Either pass the pointer by reference defining the function at least like

```
void insert(struct laptop **arr, struct laptop new_laptop, int* plen){
    *arr = realloc( (arr, (sizeof(struct laptop)*(*plen+1)));
    ( *arr )[*plen] = new_laptop;
    (*plen)++;
}
```

In this case the function will be called like

```
insert(&arr, make_laptop("Dell", "XPS", "New", 500), plen);
```

Or return a new pointer from the function like

```
struct laptop * insert(struct laptop *arr, struct laptop new_laptop, int* plen){
    arr = realloc(arr, (sizeof(struct laptop)*(*plen+1)));
    arr[*plen] = new_laptop;
    (*plen)++;

    return arr;
}
```

and the function will be called like

```
arr = insert(arr, make_laptop("Dell", "XPS", "New", 500), plen);
```

Pay attention that it is unsafe to use the same pointer in such a statement like this

```
arr = realloc(arr, (sizeof(struct laptop)*(*plen+1)));
```

the function in general can return a null pointer. As a result the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost.

You should write for example

```
struct laptop *tmp = realloc(arr, (sizeof(struct laptop)*(*plen+1)));

if ( tmp != NULL )
{
    arr = tmp;
    //...
}
```